# Campo con valor nulo en SQL Developer, en Toad muestra el valor real

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Tengo un problema, ya que al ejecutar una consulta en Toad, me muestra el valor de los registros.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutar la misma consulta en SQL Developer, me aparece vacío ese valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si sea algo del tipo de dato que soporta Developer, ya que al hacer un describe, los únicos dos campos que me manda nulo el dato, son varchar 4000, el resto sí los muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto parte del query, aunque no siento el query sea el problema, ya que en Toad sí me retorna el valor que contiene la vista, mientras que el Developer lo saca en nulo.

```
select hc.ACCOUNT_NUMBER "CLIENTE"
,hp.party_name "NOMBRE CLIENTE" 
,aps.BS_BATCH_SOURCE_NAME "ORIGEN TRANSACCIÓN"
, aps.TYPE_NAME "TIPO TRANSACCIÓN"
, aps.TRX_NUMBER "NUMERO DE DOCUMENTO"
,ra.attribute12 "UUID"
,TO_CHAR(aps.trx_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') "FECHA_DOCUMENTO"
, NVL(aps.DAYS_PAST_DUE, 0) "DIAS DE RETRASO"
, aps.DUE_DATE "FECHA VENCIMIENTO"
, aps.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE "DIVISA"
, NVL(aps.AMOUNT_DUE_ORIGINAL, 0) "ORIGINAL"
, NVL(aps.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING, 0) "SALDO DEBIDO"
, DECODE(aps.AL_STATUS_MEANING, 'Closed', 'Cerrado', 'Open', 
'Abierto') "ESTATUS"
from ar_payment_schedules_trx2_v aps, hz_cust_accounts hc, 
hz_parties hp,ra_customer_trx_all ra
WHERE hp.party_id = hc.party_id
and aps.customer_trx_id = ra.customer_trx_id
and aps.rac_customer_number = hc.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
and aps.AL_STATUS_MEANING in ('Open') 
and aps.AMOUNT_DUE_REMAINING >= 0 
and to_char(aps.trx_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') between '2022-08-01' and 
'2022-08-31'
order by FECHA_DOCUMENTO ASC, CLIENTE ASC;
```

Comment: nos mostras la consulta? igual suena a un tema de configuracion de la herramienta, no a algo de la DB...

Comment: y esa expresión en el where que dice `and aps.AL_STATUS_MEANING in ('Open')` cuando en la columna y en las imágenes estás mostrando `Abierto`. Parece indicar que las consultas, no tienen el mismo filtro.

Comment: Sí cuentan con el mismo filtro, de hecho es la misma consulta que ejecuto en ambas herramientas, sin embargo, en Developer no me muestra el dato del campo (es como si lo enmascarara), en Toad sí muestran el mismo dato. el estatus 'open' no tendría porqué impactar, ya que el decode sólo es a nivel output de los datos.

Comment: Totalmente no relacionado con tu pregunta: está raro que en el where tengas `AL_STATUS_MEANING IN ('Open')` pero hagas un DECODE en el SELECT. En teoría sólo tendrías los `Open`, no? Lo otro, ese between `and to_char(aps.trx_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') between '2022-08-01' and 
'2022-08-31'`... estás seguro que trae lo que debe traer????? Estás trabajando con CHAR y no con fechas, así que las funcionalidades de comparar fechas no se están aplicando ahí...

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, masters.

Decidí moverle a la configuración, encontré que la salida me dio en el Developer al cambiar el idioma en la configración **NLS**. Sólo cambié de español a American y voalá.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo hice en el Developer en la siguiente ruta: tools -> preferences -> database -> nls:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En caso de duda, trata de usar también la opción de execute script (creo que es F5) y no sólo execute query (F9?). Te da una salida más cercana a lo que da sql*plus o algo a más bajo nivel. Ahora bien, está curioso que el cambio en el NLS cambie la salida... dónde hiciste el cambio?